# If and else statement , test on the user account status

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make test on the **status** of the user account.
**If the account is active** I redirect him to the user page
**If the account is not active** I redirect him to login page again with an error

Here’s my code

```
<?php

require('conexion.php');

$username = '';
$password = '';

if (isset($_POST['username']) || !empty($_POST['username']))
    $username = $_POST['username'];
if (isset($_POST['password']) || !empty($_POST['password']))
    $password = $_POST['password'];

$q1 = "select * from user where username='" . $username . "' and password='" . $password . "' ";
$r1 = $db->query($q1);
$i = 0;
echo $q1;

while ($d1 = $r1->fetch()) {
    $i++;
    //$id_perso = $d1['id_perso'];
    $type = $d1['type'];
    $nom = $d1['nom'];
    $prenom = $d1['prenom'];
    $statut = $d1['statut'];
    $user_id = $d1['id_user'];
} 

if ($i == 1) { // START IF
    session_start ();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
    $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
    $_SESSION['nom'] = $nom;
    $_SESSION['prenom'] = $prenom;
    $_SESSION['statut'] = $statut;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

    if ($statut = 'actif') { 
        if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin') {
            $path = "admin/index.php";
        }
        if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'professeur') {
            $path = "professeur/index.php";
        }
        if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'doctorant') {
            $path = "doctorant/index.php";
        }

        header("Location:".$path);
    } elseif ($statut = 'inactif') {
        header("location:login.php?inactif");  
    } 
} else {
    header("location:login.php?error=1"); 
}

?>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a boolean, should be easier.

```
/*
1. Get Status from Database
2. When the user is active, you set the boolean true, else false. */
$booleanVar = false;

if($booleanVar) {
// user is active
} else {
// user is inactive
}
```

EDIT:
Redirecting with header works like this, I believe its Case Insensitive:

```
header('Location: somesite.php?abc');
```

Also you have to check values with "==" (for equal) or "===" (for identical)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the same result if you do this with a simple query:

You check if the password and the username matches AND check if the account has been activated.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' AND `statut` = 1'
```

You then can run the query and check if number of rows is greater than 0.

```
$sql = $db->query($sql);
$results = $sql->fetch();

if (count($results) > 0) {
    // Account is activated
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

You are also vulnerable to SQL-injections by inserting your variables directly into your query, wich Edhurtig noticed! The best way to prevend SQL-injections is to use PDO prepared statements.

Comment: Be sure to sanitize/escape $username and $password before dropping them in an SQL query or else you will be vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Yes, good remark! I always use PDO prepared statements though. I just demonstrated how he could achieve the same without an extra - unnecessary - if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAINTEXT**.  Do some research into secure hashing algorithms (not md5) or use a third party authentication service like Google, Facebook, Github, ect.

Second: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection via $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']

Also it was a bit unclear what was being asked but I felt it was important to point out the aforementioned issues because they are so security critical.

Here is what I was able to cleanup.  I would strongly recommend using a third party authentication service though

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$salt = "random_string";

$username='';
$password='';
if (isset($_POST['username'])||!empty($_POST['username']))     $username = $_POST['username'];
if (isset($_POST['password'])||!empty($_POST['password']))     $password = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_password = some_hashing_function_1000_times($password, $salt);

$q1="SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user`.`username` = '%s' AND `user`.`password` = '%s' LIMIT 1";

// I hope that $db has a prepare function, it prevents SQL injections from $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']
$sql = $db->prepare($q1, $username, $hashed_password);

$r1= $db->query($q1);

$user = $r1->fetch();

if( $user ) { // START IF
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
  $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
  $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
  $_SESSION['nom'] = $nom;
  $_SESSION['prenom'] = $prenom;
  $_SESSION['statut'] = $statut;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

  if($statut == 'actif'){ 
    if($_SESSION['type']=='admin') { $path="admin/index.php"; }
    if($_SESSION['type']=='professeur'){ $path="professeur/index.php"; }
    if($_SESSION['type']=='doctorant') { $path="doctorant/index.php";  }
    header("Location: " . $path);
    exit();
  }
  else if ($statut == 'inactif') {
     header("Location: login.php?inactif");
     exit();
  } 
}

header("Location: login.php?error=1"); 
exit();

// No Closing PHP tag at end of file
```

Comment: You left the main error in the OP's code: the test for status equality is using a single equals sign, using an assignment instead, always yielding `true`.